# How to solve Fresnel diffraction integral of vortex beam

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, integration, diffraction

Solving Fresnel integral for vortex beam diffraction is necessary and difficult. Without the necessary integral formula, this isn't easy to derive. Therefore, I need some means to calculate it numerically quickly. I have learned some methods, such as angular spectrum method, fast Fourier algorithm. But I still can't understand its principle and implement it through matlab programs. I think I may need some correct codes or related books to learn, and I also hope to get a good explanation so that I can understand them better.
[image: diffraction]